# SQLServer 2008 - Group by Time Range

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a table of transactions with the TransactionTime column:

[image]

How do I write a query that gives me the number of transactions in a day that occurred between certain time segments. For example starting at 9:00am up to 9:00pm with 3 hour intervals?

Sample Output:

[image]

Comment: you example does not make sense -- what is segment?

Comment: What query have you tried so far? Basically what you will need to do is calculate the interval it falls into and group on that.

Comment: You could use ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY...) to generate the `Segment` column.

Answer (score 0):

Not clear what you want to do but this should get you started -- a list of totals broken down by hour:

```
SELECT HOUR(TransactionTime), COUNT(*) AS Num_Transactions
FROM YOUR_TABLE_NAME
GROUP BY HOUR(TransactionTime)
```

If you want every 3 hours then use `HOUR(TransactionTime)/3` for your group by -- Just like normal.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all your input. I derived the following solution:

```
SELECT Datename(weekday, time)              AS weekday,
   ( ( Datepart(hour, time) / 3 ) - 3 ) AS segment,
   Count(*)                             AS num_transactions
FROM   "transaction"
GROUP  BY Datename(weekday, time),
          ( ( Datepart(hour, time) / 3 ) - 3 )
ORDER  BY CASE Datename(weekday, time)
            WHEN 'Monday' THEN 1
            WHEN 'Tuesday' THEN 2
            WHEN 'Wednesday' THEN 3
            WHEN 'Thursday' THEN 4
            WHEN 'Friday' THEN 5
            WHEN 'Saturday' THEN 6
            WHEN 'Sunday' THEN 7
          END,
          ( ( Datepart(hour, time) / 3 ) - 3 );
```